# I can't install composer globally in my web host, how can I use the "composer" command?

Tags: composer-php

I hosted my website on french host [Gandi](https://www.gandi.net/), with their simple hosting plan.

I cannot move anything in the `/usr/local/bin` directory since it is read-only, so I used to manage with composer.phar, which works well.

I recently used a library which requires the composer executable to be present (This library executes something like "composer require xxx" and there is no fallback to composer.phar).

Is there a way to make it work ?

What I have done so far :

- Tried to install composer globally (Failed because of the read-only filesystem)
- Tried to install composer globally for the current user (Failed because there was no `~/.local/bin` directory, and also failed after creating the directory and restarting the instance)
- Tried to move the file to any directory of the $PATH variable (Failed because all of these directories are read-only)
- Tried to rename composer.phar to composer, and allowed it to be executable `chmod +x composer` (Failed because it only works with the command `./composer` and not with `composer`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally succeeded with the following steps:

- renamed composer.phar to composer `mv composer.phar composer`
- made this new file executable `chmod +x composer`
- added the current path (corresponding to my website's root) to the system's $PATH variable `export PATH=$PATH:$PWD`

I'm not fully satisfied with this since this relies on a specific website's root folder, but hey, it works! I'll try to update this answer if I find a way to create a folder available for every website I'll host there.